# sinon: stub a function that is not attached to an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I'm trying to use [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to stub some functionality of [simplegit](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js).  The problem is that simplegit behaves in a very annoying fashion: `require('simple-git')` returns a function, which you need to call in order to get the object that is actually useful.  The result of this is that you get a different object each time, making stubbing with sinon (the normal way) impossible.

So I need to stub the function that gets returned by `require('sinon')`, so that I can override the bahavior of simplegit in its totality.  Basically, I want to do *something* like this (but this doesn't work):

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
var simplegit = require('simple-git')

//I'm well aware that this isn't valid
sinon.stub(simplegit).callsFake(function() {
  return {
    silent: function() {return this},
    pull: function() {console.log('pulled repo'); return this},
    clone: function() {console.log('cloned repo'); return this}
  }
}

external_function() //this function calls simplegit
```

This would result in an object that has the functions that I need, but does nothing.  It avoids the actual simplegit implementation altogether.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: There are various tools out there that make this possible, e.g. [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require), [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery), [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire). I would recommend _mock-require_, that's what I used before I switched from Mocha to Jest

Comment: I'm actually using jest. sounds like you're saying jest has a built-in way to do this?

Comment: Also, can you give an example on `proxyquire` or `mock-require`? It looks like those are the types of tools I need, but again, I can figure out how to stub when the call to `require` returns an object, but the problem is `require('simple-git')` returns a function, and I can't figure that out

Comment: Absolutely, Jest has a built-in way of handling this use case. I'll see if I can come up with an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Jest, this is easy and does not even require Sinon. You can simply use *jest.mock*, like this, for example:

```
jest.mock('simple-git', () => function() {
  return {
    silent: function() {return this},
    pull: function() {console.log('pulled repo'); return this},
    clone: function() {console.log('cloned repo'); return this}
  }
})
```

→ See [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

When I was learning how to use Jest, I've created a GitHub repo with some code example, perhaps they are useful to you:

→ https://github.com/pahund/hello-jest

Comment: using this, `require('simple-git')` still returns a function, but that function returns nothing, rather than the object with the mocked functions

Comment: It's hard to say why it's not working for you without seeing your code. Perhaps you can provide a minimal example?

Comment: i figured it out. I was using `simple-git/promise`, not `simple-git`. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ewok Could you please show an example how did you solve it?